# How to find out jquery lib into a project?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, jquery-plugins, web-parts

I 'm developing a WEB_PART and I'd like to know if there some way to find out if exists any JQUERY LIB inside the master page project where the web part is going to be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

just check

```
if (typeof window.jQuery === 'function') {
   // jQuery is defined
}
```